# getting keyerror while extracting rows using .loc[]

Tags: python, pandas, spyder

I am trying to extract rows from dataframe using `.loc[]` but getting this error:

```
KeyError: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no 
longer supported, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas- 
docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike'
```

my code is:

```
new_data = pd.get_dummies(data,drop_first=True)
features = list(set(data.columns)-set(['Price']))
x = new_data.loc[:,features].astype(float)
```

please give me a simple answer or in a way I can understand since I am new to this.

Comment: can you add a part of your dataframe and your expected output from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
features = set(data.columns.drop('Price'))
x = new_data.loc[:,features].astype(float)
```

Comment: not working , can you also tell me what this error means. thank you

Comment: If you can add a sample of data and your expected output, we can help you better.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. I got the solution. It looks like python has deprecated this method of indexing. i used "x = new_data.reindex(columns = features). "  It worked